# Satellite image display with the help of GeoServer and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

There is a satellite image. It's size is 10 GB and I need to display this image using GeoServer and OpenLayers. When user select the Satellite image in the layer switcher, I need to display image within 10 seconds.

I tried geopdf but the image quality loss isn't acceptable to customer.

I want to achieve 10 seconds response time using 32 GB satellite image.

Please advice me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would solve this problem.

1. Firstly publish the Satellite Image as a WMS service
2. Tile the service, either using the inbuilt [GeoWebCache](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/index.html) or something else.
3. Use the tiles in my OpenLayers Application